# how to set background image on login page (opencart 2.0.x)

Tags: php, content-management-system, opencart, opencart2.x

I'm running opencart 2.0.3.1 and i wanted to add a responsive background image on the admin login page (route: common/login ).
i thought on doing so by editing the header.tpl file on /admin/view/template/common and adding a php condition on the body tag where i add a class with the background if the route = "common/login".

My logic thinking:
first i want to test if there's a route (so if !landing page), if there's one then check if it equals the login route and if so, insert the "background-image" class on the tag.

here's my php code:

```
  <?php
 if(  !isset($this->request->get['route']) ){ 
       if( ((string)$this->request->get['route'] ) == "common/login"  OR ( (string)$this->request->get['route'] )=="login"  ){ 
            echo('class="login-background"'); 
       } 
 } 
?>
```

Here's my header.tpl's body tag:

```
   <body 
    <?php
       if( !isset($this->request->get['route']) ){ 
          if( ( (string)$this->request->get['route'] )=="common/login" OR ( (string)$this->request->get['route'] )=="login" ){ 
               echo('class="login-background"'); 
           }
        }
     ?>
>
```

and here's my css:

```
html, body {

    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666666;
    line-height: 18px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

body.login-background{

    background-image:url(http://example.net/image/login-admin.jpg); 
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

but i get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: route in "MYDIRECTORY"/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-admin_view_template_common_header.tpl on line 39
```

If i'm not mistaken the problem is on the "2nd if" but i don't know how to solve it (I'm still a n00b as you can see.)

Hope you can help me out!!

Comment: `http:mysite.com/image/login-admin.jpg` is not a valid URL.

Comment: yes i know that @SverriM.Olsen , it's been used as a reference only (i forgot to add the slashes),  the url on the css file is correct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add below code on admin\controller\common\header.php's index method before return

```
    $body_class = '';
    if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
        $route = (string)$this->request->get['route'];
        if ( $route == 'common/login' || $route == 'login' )
            $body_class = 'login-background';
    }
    $data['body_class'] = $body_class;
```

Second, modifiy the body tag on admin\view\template\common\header.tpl as below

```
    <body class="<?php echo $body_class; ?>">
```

==================================================================

Update:

Sorry my fault, the $this->request->get['route'] cannot access by common\header.php. This is the updated method tested on opencart 2.0.2.0:

Add argument on admin\controller\common\header.php

```
public function index($args) {
```

Add below code on admin\controller\common\header.php's index method before return

```
$body_class = '';
if (isset($args['route'])) {
    $route = (string)$args['route'];
    if ( $route == 'common/login' )
        $body_class = 'login-background';
}
$data['body_class'] = $body_class;
```

Pass parameter to common/header, modify it on admin\controller\common\login.php

```
$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header', array('route' => 'common/login'));
```

Keep common\header.tpl's body tag as below

```
<body class="<?php echo $body_class; ?>">
```

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. i added the code right BEFORE the return of the index function and then added that class in the body tag. I do not get any errors on my error.log but i still don't see anything. :/
maybe the route i wrote isn't correct? this is the URL: 
`http://example.com/admin/index.php?route=common/login`

Comment: Could you check whether the body tag include the class 'login-background' or nothing? If it included nothing, I suggest you echo the $route when you run the http://example.com/admin/index.php?route=common/login and modify $route as the right one.

Comment: this is what i added to the body tag as you advised:

'<body class="<?php echo $body_class; ?>">'

Comment: wow,this worked! thank you very much =D could you kindly tell me where did you find all the info about the opencart functions? i'd really like to study it!

Comment: In my experience, it is important to understand what the code is doing. In this case, if $this->request->get['route'] cannot be used, the other simple solution is pass the argument 'route' to common/header from common/login. As you can see, $this->load->controller is the method called common/header and we can pass array argument into it(Please check the controller method in system/engine/loader.php)